# Upgrade from SQL Server Express to Standard version, when using TFS2010?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

We're currently using SQL Server Express 2008 as backend for our TFS2010 install (Basic). Would it be possible to move to the standard (or better) version of SQL Server without any big hassels?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. In SQL Server 2008 install you can upgrade edition and then add features (Analysis, Reporting etc.) afterwards.
You can then add reporting etc. to TFS2010 through the admin console.